# How do I make a parse.com query with a NSNumber constraint?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I want to query my parse.com database retrieving objects from my House class that have a number of rooms (given in numBedrooms) equal to my NSNumber variable called roomsNeeded.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"House"];
[query whereKey:@"numBedrooms" equalTo:roomsNeeded ];
```

gives me the error: **Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC**

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
[query whereKey:@"numBedrooms" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:roomsNeeded]]
```

Comment: You can use `@(roomsNeeded)` as the modern way to create `NSNumber` from an int variable instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:roomsNeeded]`.

Comment: Totally right, however when answering i usually like to use the longer form to make sure people get where is it's coming from :)

Comment: thanks to both of you! @dusker what is this 'modern' method called so I can look it up in more detail?